# Read potentially deleted file in Bash

Tags: bash, sh, race-condition, cat

In the following code:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ ! -f "$file" ]
then
    stat --printf="%s" "$file"
    cat "$file"
else
    echo -1
fi
```

`$file` is the name of a binary file that could be deleted at any point.

My biggest fear is that the file could be deleted after `[ ! -f "$file" ]` but before `cat "$file"` is executed and the result would be incorrect.

<s>But I also wonder what will happen if the file is deleted during the execution of `cat "$file"`. Will it be fully/partially outputted, is there a risk to read unrelated characters if `$file` get overwritten on the drive? `man cat` does not explain that.</s> Edit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2031100/4503330

How can I guarantee that the output is either?

- The size of the file, followed by a new line and the content of the file
- `-1`

Note: the size of the file could be up to 5MiB and making a copy of it would be too slow.

Edit: The file is created with `ffmpeg ... -window_size 5 -extra_window_size 0 -min_seg_duration 2000000 -f dash ...` which in my case keep up to 5 files at the time in a particular directory, they never reuse the same name and they follow this cycle (entirely controlled by ffmpeg) : 1) created with .tmp extension 2) renamed without .tmp 3) (at least 10 seconds later) deleted

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What happens to an open file handler on Linux if the pointed file gets moved, delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2028874/what-happens-to-an-open-file-handler-on-linux-if-the-pointed-file-gets-moved-de)

Comment: Please edit your question to motivate it more, and explain what you are trying to do and what other processes could practically access / modify / unlink that file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot have that guarantee in bash (that the output is either the entire file prefixed by its size, or else -1), since, as you mentioned something can happen between the two commands (and processes).

BTW, that file might be truncated by some other process (doing [ftruncate(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ftruncate.2.html)...), so you cannot have any guarantee on getting the "totality" of the content.

You might consider using *advisory* [locking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lock_(computer_science)) (e.g. with [flock(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/flock.2.html) or [lockf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/lockf.3.html) ...; consider also [flock(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/flock.1.html) in a shell script), which works well only when all programs changing that file agree on that locking (so you need to adopt a whole system *convention*).

Perhaps you want to use some [RDBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database_management_system) server providing [ACID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID)-idity guarantees.

> But I also wonder what will happen if the file is deleted during the execution of cat "$file". Will it be fully/partially outputted, is there a risk to read unrelated characters if $file get overwritten on the drive?

No. If you have some process running `cat` (probably the `/bin/cat` program, see [cat(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cat.1.html)) that process keeps an opened [file descriptor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor) on the $file. So the data won't be released (or rewritten) as long as some opened file descriptor refers to that file.

Perhaps you could write a simple C program (which runs in the *same* process, in contrast to several commands in some shell script) which opens the file, uses [fstat(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fstat.2.html) (perhaps via [fileno(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fileno.3.html) if you use stdio functions) on the opened file descriptor, and loops to copy its content. That does not protect you from hostile [ftruncate(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ftruncate.2.html) done by other processes during that copy.

If you don't care about truncation or overwriting and only about premature `rm` (or [unlink(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/unlink.2.html)) you might use a temporary additional hard link. Perhaps as simple as:

```
 newhardlink=".newhardlink$$"
 ln "$file" "$newhardlink"
 stat --printf="%s" "$newhardlink"
 cat "$newhardlink"
 rm "$newhardlink"
```

If you are afraid of different filesystems, the you might do

```
 mydir=$(dirname "$file")
 newhardlink="$mydir/.newhardlink$$"
```

instead of `newhardlink=".newhardlink$$"` and you could play `trap` tricks to have the final cleanup `rm "$newhardlink"` done in all cases.

Be also aware of [inotify(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html) (probably an overkill for your situation)

Better yet, change the way `ffmpeg` is started so that it uses some temporary file (see [mktemp(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/mktemp.1.html), [mkstemp(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mkstemp.3.html))....

Or use [chepner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47394710/841108) subshell trick and in that subshell `stat --printf="%s" -L /dev/stdin` just before the `cat`

Comment: If it helps, I know that the file content won't change and also know the PID of the only process that could delete it. But I can't edit its source.

Comment: But if that process does an `ftruncate` you are stuck. Explain a bit more what is that other process.

Comment: In my case `ftruncate` cannot happen, I edited the question.

Comment: Thanks, `ln` should help, but I will still have to check if it failed or not but that's a minor change

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to not check if the file exists; just try to open it, and deal with any errors in opening the file. This is easiest to do in a subshell if that is feasible:

```
(
    exec < foo || exit 1
    cat
)
```

If you actually need to use `stat`, it's a bit tricky. BSD `stat` will process the file attached to standard input if no argument is given, but GNU `stat` (as far as I can tell) must be given an existing file name.