# When does a created file become visible to other processes in ext4?

Tags: linux, concurrency, filesystems, consistency, ext4

Consider this pseudo-code and an ext4 file system:

```
f = open("/tmp/new_file", "w")
write(f, "Test")
close(f)
```

In another process, I try to open `/tmp_newfile` immediately afterwards:

#### Questions

1. Can the other process open the file?
2. What content does the other process see? Is it `Test`?

#### Expectations

I expect (1) to be true (the metadata is probably synchronized between processes) but (2) to be false (data might be buffered)

#### More questions

3. How can I ensure that my file changes are visible to other processes? `flush` seems to work but it is bad for performance because it forces a write-to-disk. Is there something like `soft-flush` that makes the changes visible to other processes without flushing it to disk?

Answer (score -1):

> Is it guaranteed, that the other process can see the file?

No, it's not guaranteed.

A third process can delete the file, even while you have it open.

Comment: is it a POSIX standard or a Linux feature?

Comment: @ar2015  I'm not sure what you mean.  Perhaps this explains somewhat:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2028874/what-happens-to-an-open-file-handle-on-linux-if-the-pointed-file-gets-moved-del?noredirect=1

Comment: And what if it isn't deleted? I'm only concerned if the filesystem change is synced to the main file system or if the processes have their "own" view.

Comment: @GeorgSchölly *And what if it isn't deleted?* Well, then you need to specify that constraint in your question.  "Guaranteed" means the file will be visible no matter what - deletion is just one act that would break the guarantee.

Comment: I mean that if unix, free bsd and macOS also follow the same principle?