# What happens to an open file handle on Solaris if the pointed file gets moved or deleted?

Tags: solaris

What happens to an open file handle on Solaris if the pointed file gets moved, delete

As per
[What happens to an open file handle on Linux if the pointed file gets moved, delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2028874/what-happens-to-an-open-file-handle-on-linux-if-the-pointed-file-gets-moved-del)

Linux allows renaming files while there are Open FDs and opened FDs work fine.

Does the same apply to other cases ? e.g. Solaris

> Linux => Yes
>
> Windows => No
>
> Solaris ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Linux emulates the Unix/Solaris behavior of the file remaining allocated and the file contents being available until it is closed by all processes that have it open.  In other words, Linux/Solaris/UNIX all behave the same.