# Is it safe to remove the containing directory after a file in it is opened?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, directory, delete-file

I have some code that needs to return a file object and also clean up the containing directory, e.g.:

```
def create_file():
    # create a temp directory: temp_dir
    # generate a file inside the directory: filename

    file_obj = open(filename, 'rb')
    shutil.rmtree(temp_dir)
    return file_obj
```

Is it safe to remove the containing directory if I have the file handle (the result of `open()`) ?

Comment: You have to ensure that the directory is empty; you can't remove a non-empty directory.  So, if you remove the file and the directory that held it, you will be fine (on POSIX systems, anyway — Windows has its own views on what you're allowed to do).  If `shutil.rmtree` removes the entire tree, you should be okay.

Comment: Try googling "delete file open file handle". The answer depends on the OS. Here's an example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2028874/what-happens-to-an-open-file-handle-on-linux-if-the-pointed-file-gets-moved-or-d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on how you define "safe". On a linux box:

```
>>> p = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "tmpdir")
>>> def foo(p):
...     os.makedirs(p)
...     f = open(os.path.join(p, "tmp.txt"), "w")
...     shutil.rmtree(p)
...     return f
... 
>>> f = foo(p)
>>> f
<open file '/home/bruno/tmpdir/tmp.txt', mode 'w' at 0x7f14f65c2270>
>>> f.write("foo")
>>> f.close()
>>> f.name
'/home/bruno/tmpdir/tmp.txt'
>>> open(f.name).read()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/bruno/tmpdir/tmp.txt'
>>> 
>>> os.listdir(p)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/bruno/tmpdir'
```

**EDIT**

> So I can't remove the containing directory if I'm going to write to the file, do I?

Well, obviously not. And it wouldn't make any sense anyway, because, as you ask yourself:

> where does write() write in such case?

Now that's a good question...

"files" and "directories" are only a representation given by the OS. Technically, the OS writes the files data where it wants (and it can be scattered over multiple chunks at different places), and writes metadata in a known place telling which chunks belong to which "file" and which "file" belongs to which "directory".

Also, unless you specify otherwise, IO are buffered, so `write()` doesn't necessarily immediatly write anything. This being said, using an unbuffered file (and/or flushing the file after a `write`) doesn't change the behaviour of the above snippet(at least not on ubuntu-linux with python 2.7).

But anyway: the whole idea of opening a file for writing in a directory, then removing the whole directory before the file has even been used strikes me as somewhat dubious (and that's an understatement xD) - either the OS should refuse to remove the directory because it has a file in it, or it should remove the file as well as the directory, and then what's the point of writing to a file that no one will ever be able to read anyway ?

Now this really looks like a XY problem so perhaps explaining (with some context) why you "need" such a weird thing could help. Also, note that Python has [some support for temporary files and directories](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html) already

Comment: So I can't remove the containing directory if I'm going to write to the file, do I? BTW, where does `write()` write in such case?

Comment: I need the file just for reading. However, writing could be used as well if we then rewind the file, I think.

Comment: @planetp I'm afraid I didn't made myself clear. When I write "explaining (with some context)", what I'm asking is "what is the REAL problem you're trying to solve" (cf http://xyproblem.info/)