# DB queries to H2 in-file database do work after DB file deletion?

Tags: spring-boot, h2

I have local a Spring Boot server using a H2 in-file database. When booting the server the DB file is created, as expected, and I can query the database using the H2 console.

In `application.properties`:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:~/.AppData/[path to DB file]
```

While the server is running, I delete the DB file. Afterwards I can continue to query the DB with the H2 console or with the server, it works fine, which is already weird, but I suppose that the DB is loaded in memory ?

What is even more strange: using the server I can add DB records, and query them afterwards, which means that they are persisted, even if there is no DB file.

What am I missing ?

Comment: If you are running on Linux, [it doesn't actually delete the file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2028874/what-happens-to-an-open-file-handle-on-linux-if-the-pointed-file-gets-moved-or-d) until all handles to it are closed. I don't know what the behavior is for other OSes.

Comment: I'm on Windows, but that's a good point, it might be the same behaviour.